# Replace contents of innerHTML based on a concatenated variable

Tags: innerhtml, concatenation, var

sorry for the simple question but I'm a newbie and I just can't get the right Google search to find the answer. Need to replace the contents of the innerHTML based on a variable which includes a randomly generated number. At the moment it's printing the name of the variable rather than the value it contains. Help please!

```
function startClick() {

var used = false;

function checkNums(used) {
return used == randomQNum;
}

function writeQuestion() {
    //populate question field & 4 answer fields all based on the randomly generated number 'randomQNum'
        //fields are called:
            // question0 
            // answer0a
            // answer0b
            // answer0c
            // answer0d
    
    var qNumber = "question" + randomQNum;
    var box1Number = "answer" + randomQNum + "a";
    var box2Number = "answer" + randomQNum + "b";
    var box3Number = "answer" + randomQNum + "c";
    var box4Number = "answer" + randomQNum + "d";
    
    
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = qNumber;
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = box1Number;
    document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML = box2Number;
    document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML = box3Number;
    document.getElementById("box4").innerHTML = box4Number;
}



randomQNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    //creates a random number between 1 & how many questions there are.
window.console.log("random number = " + randomQNum); //prints the number

checkNums(); //need this to call the function!
trueCheck = (usedNums.some(checkNums))
window.console.log("random number found in array = " + trueCheck);


// IF THAT NUMBER IS FOUND IN usedNums ARRAY generate a new number: 
if (trueCheck == true) {
    randomQNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    window.console.log("attempt2: " + randomQNum);
    window.console.log("used = " + used);
    checkNums(); //calls the function
} else {
    usedNums.push(randomQNum); //adds new random number to array
    window.console.log(usedNums);  //reprints array
    writeQuestion();
        //calls function to generate question from the chosen random number.
};
```

};

Comment: Can you reduce the code so the problem is more clear? it's hard to understand the issue

Comment: Sure, it's just the `function writeQuestion(){}` section. At the moment it is returning the concatenated string e.g. "question4" rather than the content of the variable called question4.

Comment: I guess you can do something like `window[qNumber]` to get the variable with that name.